# How do I pass a prop from from component to getServerSideProps() in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, getserversideprops

I want to pass a props from my component to getServerSideProps(). They are both on the same page. I the code below I want pass url from my component to getServerSideProps() so that I can use the same url to get the data from API.

```
export default function Home({data}) {
  
  const [number, getNumber] = useState("9999999999")
  const url =`{http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=e52d69f119348057d68ec090d2d10978&number=${number}}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Numverify</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <div className="h-16 dark:bg-gray-900 bg-white shadow-md flex justify-center items-center">
          <span className="text-gradient font-bold text-xl">NumVerify</span>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass data to `getServerSideProps` from your component, the data flows the other way around, from `getServerSideProps` to your React component.

Comment: So what should I use in place of getServerSideProps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recall getServerSideProps from same component with updated api url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299462/how-to-recall-getserversideprops-from-same-component-with-updated-api-url)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have misunderstood what `getServerSideProps` does.

The docs state:

> If you export an async function called getServerSideProps from a page,
> Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data
> returned by getServerSideProps.

So the data that you return will be passed to your `Home` component, not the other way round.

Comment: So what should I use in place of getServerSideProps?